# Key in Alpine.data() is undefined when using a script tag

Tags: alpine.js

I have a Django template that includes a script tag for Alpine.js (v3.10.2):

```
<div x-data="product" class="product">
  ...
</div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('product', () => ({
      count: 1,
      increment() {
        this.count = this.count++
      },
      decrement() {
        this.count = this.count--
      }
    }))
  })
</script>
```

This is as per the [docs for Alpine.data()](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data). However, this results in the error:

```
Alpine Expression Error: product is not defined
Expression: "product"
```

The problem does not occur when I set the data directly in the x-data attribute:

```
<div x-data="{ count: 1 }" class="product">
  ...
</div>
```

I am including the alpinejs script using the `defer` option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the Alpine.js component (using e.g. the arrow syntax):

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('product', () => ({
      count: 1,
      increment() {
        this.count++
      },
      decrement() {
        this.count--
      }
    }))
  })
</script>
```

Comment: You are correct, this is missing from my code - however, when I add it I still see the same error.

Comment: Where do you include Alpine.js' script exactly? Is this component's `<script>` above or under it?

Comment: It's included in my base template, which this template inherits from. I've confirmed that Alpine works with the more standard `x-data` attribute. The problem seems to occur in the HTML where "product" is used, NOT in the JS script tag.

Comment: The error is resolved if I move this script tag higher up the template hierarchy, so it seems like something to do with accessing the variable before it's declared.

Comment: With `defer` you should put Alpine.js in the `<head>` section not before the end of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue because of a typo in html code:

```html
<template>
...
<template>
```

As you may see the slash is missing in closing `template` tag, so the proper code should be:

```html
<template>
...
</template>
```

In this specific case the error is way too misleading, as you may think that some sort of race-condition in script init is involved, but it is way more straightforward.